# How to convert all published wordpress posts to draft of one user.?

Tags: wordpress

I want to change all published posts by user A to drafts if A's user role changes. I could not find any such examples. How can I achieve this?

for example, I have three custom roles for users.
1.Free
2 Business
3.Enterprise

If a user role is changed to business to free his posts should be made drafts.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will do it (you might need to change it to the correct role slug).

```
function set_posts_to_draft($user_id, $role) {
    if($role === "free") {
        $user_posts = get_posts(array(
            'author' => $user_id,
            'post_type' => 'your_custom_post_type'
        ));
        if($user_posts) {
            foreach($user_posts as $user_post) {
                $updated = array( 'ID' => $user_post->ID, 'post_status' => 'draft' );
                wp_update_post($updated);
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action('set_user_role', 'set_posts_to_draft', 2 , 10 );
```

Comment: how can we select custom post type instead of post?